# How to speed up PDF display in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, php-7.1

I am running symfony 3.4 to render a PDF file based on some user answers.

The PDF is generated and then shown on the browser via

```
 return $this->file('invoice_3241.pdf', 'my_invoice.pdf', ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
```

Unfortunately it takes a very long time (over 30 seconds) to see the PDF on the screen.

I debugged the application and noticed that if I put a breakpoint on the return above, once the debugger reaches the breakpoint i can resume the program (continue) and press stop straight away (in the debugger) and the PDF will load in 2 seconds.

All that symfony seems to be doing is "tidying up".

Is there a way to display the PDF and stop anything else? or maybe run the "tidying up" manually before the PDF is rendered?

Thanks

Edit:
What takes the longest is this line in app.php (30 seconds)

```
$response->send();
```

Comment: Are you trying to test it in locale or in production? There are no Listeners/Events/or other stuffs that runs in background after the Response was sent?

Comment: locale, but the problem exists in prod as well. When I run the debug step by step I don't see any Listeners/Events.